# Como creo un elemento "a" a partir de un string y ejecuto la url

Tags: javascript, jquery

Obtengo siempre links parecidos a este, necesito ejecutar el enlace para ejecutar la redirección.

Pensaba hacerlo con **location.href**

`location.href ="http://xxx.com/index.php?x=xx";`

Pero requeriría de extraer solo el enlace y no creo que se pueda ya que los enlaces varían.

```js
let enlace = ' <a  class="btn" href=http://xxx.com/index.php?x=xx>Ir al enlace</a>';
console.log(enlace);
```

Pensaba hacerlo con **RegExp** pero no creo que se pueda por la variación de los caracteres.

La ultima posibilidad que se me ocurre es crear el elemento a partir de ese string y ejecutar dicho enlace para el reenvió, creo que es lo mas viable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear el elemento con jQuery y recuperar el atributo `href`:

```js
var enlace = $(' <a  class="btn" href=http://xxx.com/index.php?x=xx>Ir al enlace</a>');
console.log(enlace.attr('href'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gracias hermano.